# Эмуляция клавиатуры в chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Необходимо на странице в chrome заполнить текстовые поля путём эмуляции клавиатурного ввода, т.е. посимвольно. Не удаётся сгенерить событие клавиатуры в chrome. Вот пример тестовой страницы где пытаюсь вывести в текстовое поле символ "7":

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function emul(){
            var event = document.createEvent("Events");
            event.initEvent("keyup", true, false);
            event.keyCode = 55;
            event.which = 55;
            document.getElementById('elem1').dispatchEvent(event);
        };

     </script>
</head>
<body>
     <input type="button" onclick="emul()" value="test"/>
     <input type="text" id="elem1"/>
</body>
```

Сейчас при нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит. Подскажите рабочий вариант

Comment: Расскажите об изначальной задаче. Вам необходимо анимировать добавление текста? Это можно сделать иначе. Вашим способом вы можете сгенерировать событие нажатия клавиши, но не добавить текст ей соответствующий.

Comment: Необходимо на сайте заполнить текстовые поля input, но простое присвоение document.getElementById('elem1').value='example' соответствующему полю не срабатывает, т.к. сайт проверяет вводимый текст при вводе. Т.е. если сначала программно присвоить значение, а потом допустим взять и мышкой щёлкнуть по полю, то запуститься проверка на регулярку. Как вызвать данную проверку программно я не знаю, поэтому хочу сделать так, сначала присвоить значение, а затем сгенерить клавиатурное или мышиное событие для данного поля.